# When will the V2 barcode scanning model be available in the unbundled version for barcode scanning

Tags: google-mlkit

Looking at the documentation found here
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

It says that the unbundled version uses V2 of the barcode scanning model which has performance and accuracy improvements. When will these improvements be included in the Google Play services version( unbundled version)?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a committed timeline for providing the unbundled barcode v2 in Google Play Services yet, but we are working on it and hope to make it available in a couple of months. In the meantime, you can use the unbundled barcode v2 in Google Play Services to see if that fits your need.